# SSRS Backup files being created in VS 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2012, ssdt-bi

Multiple  - Backup.rdl files are being created in the project folder which is giving me a huge headache with Source Control with SSDT in VS 2017. Has anyone figured out how to stop these being created ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One workaround for this for those using GIT as source control has been pointed to me offline, and that is adding

```
*- Backup*.rdl
```

to the .gitignore file. The question still remains about having a possible option somewhere to turn the creation of the files somewhere in Visual Studio.

Another reason that I have found for the creation of the files is using a template that was created in VS 2013. When using the template, VS upgrades it to the latest version of SSRS xml schema and that leads to a backup file being created during the upgrade. Recreating the template in VS 2017 has stopped creating any additional -Backup.rdl files.